# Base URL of CouchDB

Tags: java, android, couchdb

When I enter my base URL it refuses to connect, which means I probably have the wrong URL. This is what I currently have:

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/";
```

What would the base URL be? Any examples would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The localhost refers to the device on which the code is running, in this case the emulator.

There is however a far better solution. You can access your host machine with the IP address "10.0.2.2".

This has been designed in this way by the Android team. So your webserver can perfectly run at localhost and from your Android app you can access it via `http://10.0.2.2:5984/_utils/`

please try with below code

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:5984/_utils/";
```

Comment: So that would be my base URL?